# backbone.js RESTful API save does not add new id to model

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, backbone.js

i am new to backbone.js and i am trying to make a simple model work with a restful API but i cant seem to make the simple POST operation work.

from what i understand if a model element does not have the property "id" set and the save() function is called, the model will issue a post command to the server (the url of the model)
and will need to receive back an HttpStatus.OK (200) and the new id of the item.

here is the JS code:

> ```
>   this.model = new MYAPP.menuItem();
>   this.model.save();
>   console.debug("the new id is:", this.model.get("id")) <-- this is undefined
> ```

i am using spring controller as the server side. this is the controllers code

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/menuItem",method = RequestMethod.POST)
> @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK )
> @ResponseBody
> public Long addmenuItem(Model model) {
>     return new Long(1);
> }
> ```

The Post call is reaching the server ok and the controller is called but as you can see the id of the model is not beeing updated.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks.

Additional code as requested:

> ```
>     initialize: function() {
>   console.debug("initializing new view");
>   this.model = new MYAPP.Event();
>   this.model.save({
>       success: function( model ) {
>         console.log( model.get('id') );
>       }
>     });
>   var source   = $("#index-template").html();
>   this.template = Handlebars.compile(source);
>   console.debug("view collection", this.model);
>   this.model.on('all', this.render, this);
>   //this.recipes.fetch();
> },
> ```

sorry for the mess!.

Comment: You can try using model.save({wait: true, success: function(d){// process code... }}); as well to wait for the server to return the id before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.save()` method is asynchronous. As so, the `id` isn't returned by the server right away. Try it like this:

```
var self = this;
this.model.save().done(function() { console.log( self.model.get('id') ); });
```

**edit** As you have trouble with reference to your object, you can have the same result this way around:

```
this.model.save({
  success: function( model ) {
    console.log( model.get('id') );
  }
});
```

**edit after [some chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22680/discussion-between-simon-boudrias-and-gleeb)** Seems like the returned data wasn't valid. After a save, the server should return the full object encoding with json (with the id).

Comment: cannot call method get of undefined, but i do see it at the end of the process hence the ASYNC.

Comment: You added the `var self = this` part? If you keep a reference to your object, you'll be able to log it's `id` like I showed you.

Comment: what am i doing undefined is the output from
console.log("what am i doing",  self.model.get('id')

Comment: The error you get on the console tell that the attribute `model` of the object `self` is undefined. This mean that `self` could be pointing to the wrong object - or that the `model` attribute is deleted at some point.

Comment: I edited my answer with another way around which don't involve keeping a reference to your object.

Comment: i guess the self is long gone by the end of the function. let me try the other way!

Comment: the second way doesn't call the the success function, tried stopping with brake point as well

Comment: You're using raw backbone or are you integrating with a plugin? (localstorage, paginator, etc)

Comment: simple backbone on the client and spring on the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22680/discussion-between-simon-boudrias-and-gleeb)